# CKT Abbreviation

Tags: symbol

From time to time, I have encountered the abbreviation "CKT" for "circuit".

No common language (English, German, French, Spanish) has a word with K for circuit.

What is the meaning of this?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This site:

[MikeHolt CKT Origins](https://forums.mikeholt.com/threads/abbreviation-origin.91503/page-3)

Makes the claim that it comes from MIL-STD-12:

[image: CKT Origin]

A copy of MIL-STD-12 is provided at:

[MIL-STD-12](https://www.product-lifecycle-management.com/download/MIL-STD-12D.pdf)

In there you can see the CKT abbreviation:

[image: CKT Abbreviation]

This is a very old (and now obsolete) MIL-STD but why is likely anyone's guess.  In my experience there is often little logic to things standardized by the US Military either historically or currently.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it came from the pronunciation.

The "c" in the middle of circuit is pronounced as a "hard c" which sounds the same as a "k". So "ckt" is a reasonable representation of the three most important sounds in the word circuit.

It's also quite possible that "cct" was already taken when the abreviation was introduced. MIL-STD-12 has "cct" as "circle cutting" which seems likely to be a term that was already in use before electronic circuits became a thing.